# unordered_map of vectors resetting vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I am trying to build a class to handle key callbacks.

To do this I have a map defined as so:

```
class Keyboard {
public:
   void registerCallback(int key, callback_fn func, bool repeat = false);
   void onKeyEvent(int key, int state);

private:
    typedef std::function<void (int)> callback_fn;

    struct Callback {
        Callback(callback_fn f, bool r)
            : func(f), repeat(r), last_state(-1) {}

        callback_fn func;
        bool repeat;
        int last_state;
    };

    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Callback>> callbacks;
};
```

I then register callbacks like so:

```
void Keyboard::registerCallback(int key, callback_fn func, bool repeat) {
    // My understanding is that if there is nothing mapped to the key
    // it will create a new vector. Otherwise it will return the mapped
    // object. I did try checking if anything already exists at the key
    // and if not creating a new vector but it yielded the same results.
    callbacks[key].push_back({ func, repeat });
}
```

However I am having an issue where the mapped vector appears to lose all of it's elements.

When I register a callback the vector at the given key increases in size but when I try to iterate over the vector in another method, it has no elements.

Below is how my method for iterating over the vector.

```
void Keyboard::onKeyEvent(int key, int state) {
    for(auto& callback : callbacks[key]) {
        if(callback.repeat || callback.last_state != state) {
            callback.func(state); 
        }
    }
}
```

Note if I add `std::cout << callbacks[key].size() << std::endl;` to the top of the function it prints `0`.

If it matters here is an example of how I register a callback.

```
keyboard.registerCallback('w', [](int state) {
    std::cout << "w " << (state == GLFW_PRESS ? "pressed" : "released") << std::endl;
}, true);
```

I suspect my problem stems from differences between Java's maps, which I am more used to, and C++'s maps

Comment: What does the following print right after registerCallback call: `std::cout << keyboard.callbacks['w'].size();` ?

Comment: When you retrieve the vector of callbacks are you sure you're using the same instance of `callbacks` as when you added them?

Comment: Are these the only functions being called that modify `callbacks`?  And are you sure that you're not creating and operating on a copy of `callbacks` somewhere?

Comment: There is only one instance of `callbacks`, it's all held within a Singleton class, `Keyboard` and these are the only functions that can access `callbacks` Sorry, that was not clear above, I've updated to try reflect that.

Comment: Have you tried a test call `keyboard.onKeyEvent('w', true)` right after `keyboard.registerCallback()`? Does it find the registered entry? if yes, then someone definitely modifies or creates another `keyboard` object.

Comment: @lerp It's held in a singleton but is it _really_ a singelton?

Comment: @Inspired I just checked the size after `registerCallback` is exited and it is returning the expected `1`. So the problem lies in fetching the element in `onKeyEvent`, I believe.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I just check whether they are the same `Keyboard` objects and they are. I did this by getting the address of the `keyboard` used to call `registerCallback` and by getting the address of `this` inside of `ònKeyEvent`

Comment: Yes, it looks so. It may be useful also to check size of `callbacks` (the whole map) at the beginning of `onKeyEvent`. If it's zero then the map doesn't reset the vectors, it's just empty. And if it's not - make sure it already contains the needed key (you may just use `at()` instead of `[]` in the `onKeyEvent`; if you get an exception, then you have not registered the key in the map).

Comment: @Inspired I changed the loop in `onKeyEvent` to use `at()` instead. This provides an exception. So for some reason, some where, it removes the vector from the map?

Comment: Or it's a different key, or it's not registered yet. I'd suggest the following: put `std::cout << "Registering " << key << std::endl;` at the beginning of the `registerCallback()` and `std::cout << "Looking up for " << key << std::endl;` at the beginning of the `onKeyEvent`. Do you see the outputs in a correct sequence and with the same numeric key value? (To be 100% sure I'd add a `cout` inside the constructor of `Keyboard` object.)

Comment: @Inspired Ahh, you were right initially. GLFW (the library I am using to get key events) always passes the pressed key in uppercase. So `onKeyEvent` is being fed a key value of `87` which is uppercase W. I interpreted your initial answer as "do you have caps lock on when pressing w" instead of is it trying to access the element at key 'W' and not 'w'. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess: the problem is that you receive key code as a capital letter (`'W'`; alphabetic key codes are most often upper-case), but register a callback for a small letter (`'w'`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely a matter of case sensitivity, as there is nothing particularly special about your code and 10 seconds in a debugger confirms that nothing magical is going on. As long as you are using the same instance of "Keyboard" through out, then the only reason it would not find the 'key' you are looking for is because it's different than they key you registered.

Did you step through in a debugger and determine what key you were searching for? Did you try outputting it?

If you have to deal with variable case, then you can always overload 'unordered_map' to use a custom hashing function which can make a caseless comparison for you.